# How to make a 2 dimensional list using for loop?

Tags: python, list, opencv

I'm trying to detect circles from loaded image and save the center values to an array.
I tried different methods including using for loops, append, numpy, list, but it wasn't successful by far.

```
def slot_make_pixmap(self, img, param1=10, param2=10, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0):
    self.img = img
    circle_centers = []
    center = []
    dst = img.copy()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 100, param1=param1, param2=param2, minRadius=minRadius, maxRadius=maxRadius)
    # print('circles: ', circles[0])
    for i in range(circles.size):
        center.append([circles[i][0], circles[i][1]])
        circle_centers.append(center)
        print('circle centers2: ', circle_centers[i])
    try:
        for i in circles[0]:
            cv2.circle(dst, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 5)
            print('circle centers: ', (i[0],i[1]))
            # circle_centers[i] = [i[0],i[1]]
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        pass
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Python\Projects\Sensor\widget_result_camera.py", line 32, in slot_make_pixmap
    center.append([circles[i][0], circles[i][1]])
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

**What I tried:**
using for loops:

```
        circle_centers = []
        for i in range(circles.size):
            center = []
            center.append([circles[i][0], circles[i][1]])
            circle_centers.append(center)
            print('circle centers2: ', circle_centers[i])
```

Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Your question is not clear enough to understand. Give some example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it like below:

```
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 100, param1=param1, param2=param2, minRadius=minRadius, maxRadius=maxRadius)
centers = []
if circles is not None:
    circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")
    for (x, y, r) in circles:
        cv2.circle(orig, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        centers.append((x, y))
print(centers)
```